# Pandas read.csv with chinese letters

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

I want to read a csv with chinese letters. I use an "," dilimiter with an UTF-8 encoding. The problem is Python generates an "Unnamed: 0" column and i do not understand why. The encoding itself seems to work.

Code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/MyLady17/Downloads/data2.csv", "utf-8", delimiter = ",")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard quoting rules for csv says that `"` are quoted by doubling, so in your line starting with 3, the four `""""` are interpreted as two quoted `"`.

You don't show the end of the line, but perhaps the initial `"` on each line shouldn't be there?

See quotechar, quoting, and doublequote in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html for more info.

Comment: thank you, very good point. Is there a way to tell Python that """" is not a quoted "" ?

Comment: Yes, using the quotechar, quoting, and doublequote parameters to `read_csv()` -- but it does look like they are quoting something since there are four of them in a row...

Comment: No, "" seems to be the same like NA.

Comment: Ok, so what is the correct split of the first 3-4 columns in the line starting with 3?

Comment: dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/MyLady17/Downloads/data2.csv", "utf-8", delimiter = ",", na_values = "''")

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 80. I guess there is something wrong with my data. Got to check it with my colleague. Thank you so far :-)